# Symfony / Doctrine : Getting the first maximum value from database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been stuck for somewhile on this :

I want to extract the value 'points' from my table 'seuils' by sorting with a DESC the column 'datevalidite'.

The SQL works fine :

```
SELECT points FROM seuils ORDER BY datevalidite DESC
```

But the code that i've implemented into the controller of my Symonfony returns me an error :

```
$dataSeuils = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$seuils = $dataSeuils->createQuery(
    'SELECT points 
    FROM AppBundle:Seuils
    ORDER BY datevalidite DESC')->getResult();
```

And here's the error message :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 53: Error: Expected end of string, got 'BY'
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
>
> 1 linked Exception:
>
> QueryException »

At the end I need to extract the attribute points of my Entity that is returned.

But I really don't understand why it works properly in phpMyAdmin (The SQL) but not in Symfony.

Here's a snipp of my SQL code that creates the table :

```
CREATE TABLE `seuils` (
    `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `datevalidite` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Repository:**

```
$dataSeuils = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Seuils');

$seuils = $dataSeuils->createQueryBuilder('points')->orderBy('points.datevalidite', 'DESC')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an table alias in your DQL as follow:

```
    $seuils = $dataSeuils->createQuery(
            'SELECT s.points 
            FROM AppBundle:Seuils s
            ORDER BY s.datevalidite DESC')->getResult();
```

Hope this help